# Script using old version of jQuery; How do I make it use the newer version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, version, deferred

I have two versions of jQuery on a site that I am working on, and the older version may be needed for some things, but one of my scripts is breaking because it is using the older version, and I get this error:

```
l.Deferred is not a function
```

I tried to use the newer version of jQuery by adding the jQuery script before my main.js script, and wrapping my main script in jQuery with the version specified.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>jq11 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src="/sites/all/themes/wma2/js/main.js"></script>
```

and then in main.js:

```
(function($){
    window.matchMedia || (window.matchMedia = function() {
        "use strict";
        var t = window.styleMedia || window.media;

        function r(t, e, i) {
        if (!(this instanceof r)) return new r(t, e);
        "string" == typeof t && (t = document.querySelectorAll(t)),
            this.elements = n(t), this.options = s({}, this.options),
            "function" == typeof e ? i = e : s(this.options, e), i &&
            this.on("always", i), this.getImages(), l && (this.jqDeferred =
                new l.Deferred);
        var o = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            o.check()
        })
    }

   ......

})(jq11);
```

You can see the issue on my site [here](http://wma2.stage.pgdonors.org/#)

Comment: May I ask as why you would ever need two versions of jQuery on the same page? 1.11.3 is very old and I would suggest rewriting main.js in such a way that it can be handled by the newer jQuery version. This is probably less work than fixing everything that breaks when including both versions.

Comment: I was handed this site from my clients so honestly I don't know why they have multiple versions, or if they're necessary. But I'm trying to fix this error in a way that won't risk breaking anything else on the site.

Comment: `l` is not defined in the code shown, so `l.anythingAtAll` will fail. Are you missing some other code from this example?